# Libphonenumber can get country code and country name?

Tags: android, country-codes

I want the format 
like `IN-INDIA   +91-7679030608..
Where IN is the countryISO,India is the country name and +91 is the country code..`

My question is can I get these 3 information CountryISO,Country Name and Country code from [libphonenumber.jar](https://code.google.com/p/libphonenumber/)
file???
If it is possible then what is the code???please tell me how can I fetch??

Answer (score -3):

It is possible with this library . It is simple.

Here is example that solves your problem :

http://javacodeimpl.blogspot.in/2013/11/google-libphonenumber-to-validate-phone.html#.U_V4F7ySwbY

Comment: This does not answer the question. The referenced post tells how to retrieve the country code. Not the actual name.

Comment: this is not answering OP question. The example only returns the region code